# How to import a NPM package into browser's console

Tags: javascript, browser-console

Just to play around with some package functions I want to import it into my browser's console. I have tried this approach, but it gives a parsing error.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://unpkg.com/libphonenumber-js@1.7.26/core/index.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

The errror I am getting,

> parsePhoneNumberFromString.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use
>   import statement outside a module

I am trying to use `parsePhoneNumberFromString` function into my browser's console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use ES6 modules from dev tools console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569996/how-to-use-es6-modules-from-dev-tools-console)

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `<script>` tags to import modules like that, or if you do, you do it within the script itself using an [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) statement like `import * as reduxSaga from "https://unpkg.com/redux-saga@1.0.3/dist/redux-saga-effects.esmodules-browsers.js"`.

The key thing is to set the [`type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-type) on the `<script>` tag so that it is `type="module"` that way it knows to load the script as a module (which allows `import` `export`).

For example:

### `index.js`

```js
import {parsePhoneNumberFromString} from "https://unpkg.com/libphonenumber-js@1.7.26/core/index.js";

const pnStr = "555-555-5555";
const pn = parsePhoneNumberFromString(pnStr);
console.log(pn);
```

### `index.html`

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="index.js" type="module"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```