# How do I load NPM packages in browser dev tools console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

Doing it this way:

```
const _ = await import('https://unpkg.com/lodash')
```

gives me a strange object with single `Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)` prop valued `"Module"`.

*Note 1:* I'm aware of the trick

```
import _ from 'lodash'
window._ = _
```

in your code, please give your answer only if the import works directly from browser's dev tools console.

*Note 2:* I'm also aware that this question has been asked [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58921161/how-to-import-a-npm-package-into-browsers-console) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569996/how-to-use-es6-modules-from-dev-tools-console). I read through all the answers, they either do not work nowadays or are inapplicable because of *Note 1*. So I decided to ask it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a lodash specific thing I recon as it uses an IIFE

```
await import("https://unpkg.com/lodash");
console.log(_, window._);
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm marking this as answer because after more research I reached the similar conclusion that the module export is not how browsers handle scripts and hence your code is somewhat analogous to **document.body.appendChild(Object.assign(document.createElement("script"), {type:'text/javascript', src:'https://unpkg.com/lodash'}))** which just loads the script and runs it. And whatever globals that script adds is how you use it. At this point I assume there's no way to load the script as a module and get either its named or default exports. If there is a way please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Here a small helper function that I find handy to load ESM packages from NPM in the dev console:

```js
/**
 * Load an ESM package from npm in your JavaScript environment.
 *
 * Loads packages from https://www.npmjs.com/ via the CDN https://www.jsdelivr.com/
 *
 * Usage:
 * 
 *     const lodash = await npm('lodash-es')
 *     const lodash = await npm('lodash-es@4')
 *     const lodash = await npm('lodash-es@4.17.21')
 *
 *     lodash.uniq([1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2]) // [1, 3, 2]
 */
async function npm(name) {
  return await import(`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/${name}/+esm`)
}
```

See gist: https://gist.github.com/josdejong/3d176fa90efa36ed51ab6a4e8810074e