# Use All of App's Imports in Javascript Console?

Tags: javascript, debugging, dynamic, console, global

When I'm in debug console for JS (during debug of a given source file), and I try to use a module that was imported in my source file, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: myModule is not defined
```

It seems this will work for importing javascript modules for use in debugging console:

```
import myModule from '/path/to/module.js';
window.myModule = myModule;

// in the console:
myModule.foo();
```

(See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56738910/12728698) for more details...)

I want to be able to do this for all of the module imports in a given file, is this easily possible?

Psuedo-code:

```
for (i = 0; i < num_modules; i++) {
  window[module.name] = modules[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to do what you are asking using static ES6 module imports. You could probably create your own method for performing imports by making use of [dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports) that could then attach the imported modules to the `window`, or else use a module loader/bundler that allows you to hook into the import process or otherwise exposes the list of imports.