# Play MIDI files in the browser (using timidity)

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, es6-modules, midi

I want to play MIDI files in the browser smoothly (even when the browser tab is not in focus, and be able to get and set the time position).

The [readme of `timidity`](https://github.com/feross/timidity#usage) says that I should start with

```
const Timidity = require('timidity')
```

but I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

I tried many workarounds but all of them yield other errors. For example, [`import('/127.0.0.1:8887/node_modules/timidity/index.js')`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65462766/5231110) while running [Web Server for Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46480984/5231110) yields `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module` (even though opening that URL in the browser works). I tried applying `browserify` to `timidity` and [`bg-sound`](https://github.com/feross/bg-sound), adding `type="module"` to various `<script>` tags, but I haven't found a combination that allows my script to do something like `new Timidity()`.

`browserify index.js -o bundle.js` (using [`index.js` from `bg-sound`](https://github.com/feross/bg-sound/blob/master/index.js) after running `npm install bg-sound` in the directory where that `index.js` is) allows doing

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<bg-sound src="https://bitmidi.com/uploads/16752.mid"></bg-sound>
Click somewhere. Until then, there will probably be "The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page."
```

but then I didn't find a way to access `player` or `timidity` in order to use [`player.seek()`](https://github.com/feross/timidity#playerseekseconds).

How can I play MIDI files?

Answer (score 0):

### Other answers than this [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) are very welcome. I particularly wonder about the purpose of `browserify` and whether there's a simpler solution without it.

Anyway, after a cascade of errors and respective workarounds, I've come up with the following modification of the official example:

Run once:

```
npm install timidity
npm install -g browserify
```

HTML file:

```html
<script src="myscript-browserified.js"></script>
Click somewhere within the first 5 seconds! Otherwise there will be no sound due to "The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page."
```

File `myscript.js`:

```js
const Timidity = require('timidity')

setTimeout(() => {
    baseUrl = 'https://bitmidi.com/timidity/' // for fetching the file libtimidity.wasm
    const player = new Timidity(baseUrl)
    player.load('https://bitmidi.com/uploads/16752.mid')
    player.play()

    player.on('playing', () => {
      console.log(player.duration)
    })
}, 5000);
```

After modifying `myscript.js`, run the following command

```
browserify myscript.js -o myscript-browserified.js
```